# remove jboss default jar el-api.jar from classpath

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, jasper-reports, classloader

I am using `Jboss 4.2.1` to deploy a web application that uses `jsp-2.1.jar` and some other jars.. the `jasper classes` in this jar uses latest version of `EL API(1.2)`.

Jboss has only `EL 1.1(I mean the el-api.jar)` so it throwing noSuchMethod error during jboss launch..

can you please suggest how to exclude this jar from class path/ load latest jars(like `jsp-api-2.1.jar`) before this jar.

```
Exact Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
javax.el.ExpressionFactory.newInstance()Ljavax/el/ExpressionFactory;
```

Comment: Whenever I'm coming to problem like this I manually delete the conflicting class from the one of the conflicting jars.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and it works but I might need to keep the jar for other projects. so want to know if there is any dependency that can be provided through XML, to load third party jars prior to default lib jars.

Comment: What I usually do is I put a suffix to the modified jar like `myjar-1.0.3-modified.jar` to indicate that this jar is not the original one.